# Can I delete this NSIS uninstall folder from my computer?

Tags: nsis

I found this folder "NSIS Uninstall Information" on my computer and would like to delete it. Is it okay if I do that because I keep seeing on the internet that it is Adware or something like that.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) is a tool used to create installers/uninstallers but [some malware](https://kichik.com/2008/02/08/mediacentric/) has also used the name to try to seem legitimate.

"NSIS Uninstall Information" is not a folder that most NSIS installers will create but that does not mean that it is impossible for a genuine software installation to use this directory.

You could run regedit.exe and see if anything under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` references those two GUID paths.

Does Windows Defender say anything about those folders? [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com)?

If it is not malware and you delete the folders then those programs might not uninstall correctly. You could probably just reinstall the software on top of the old install if that turns out to be a issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I looked at the .ini files with notepad++ and I kept seeing Cyberlink Power DVD14. Apparently, it's the uninstaller for it so I'll just leave the folder there.